# create app with synchronization of remote files in Android studio

Tags: java, android, button, synchronization

I am developing my app which contains some xml files used by some internal routines.
I would like to have the original xml files stored in a remote server, so that when a synchronization with such server is required by the user, the app updates the xml files, i.e. the version of the files present in remote is downloaded in local. Is it possible to realize such a setup? Is it possible to add a synchronize button inside the app? I develop in Android studio. For the moment, my app contains the local version of the xml files,
and the synchronization is missing.

Comment: ??, I mean, just download thesefiles when needed and use them, can you explain a bit more?

Comment: These files are just xml files part of my app. I would like to have the official version in remote, and when I press a button, the local version of the files is replaced by the remote one. This would be the idea. I don't know if it is duable, i.e. I don't know if it is possible to have an update of the local files once the app is installed. Maybe one should reinstall the whole app to have the updated version of the xml files?

Comment: Are these XML files layout files or just other files that you use in your code?

Comment: they are files that I use in my code. They are in the directory "res/values". By the way, does it make a difference?

Comment: If the case that these XML files are layout files, it's not possible because lots of optimizations are done at build time.

The workaround would be creating tge layout programmatically

If not, you can just keep the local files somewhere like /Android/your.app.name/files/ and download and replace th when needed, please tell me what case is yours so I can answer your question

Comment: in my case these xml files are not layout files. They are resources that I use to create a sqlite database. I suppose the database is created each time the app is launched, based on the local version of the xml files, so if I was able to have them in remote and replace them (not only me, but each user that has my app) by pressing a button, I would have the synchronization wished. What do you suggest to do?

Comment: I forgot to say that at the end of the story I will put my files in a remote server and each owner of my app would update his own files with such files that are stored in remote. This is the idea that i'm trying to realize.

Answer (score 0):

Since these are not layout XML files,

Use something like this to download the file you need:

```
URL website = new URL("http://www.website.com/some_file.xml");
ReadableByteChannel rbc = Channels.newChannel(website.openStream());
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("some_file.xml");
fos.getChannel().transferFrom(rbc, 0, Long.MAX_VALUE);
fos.close();
```

Put such block of code in the onClick method of the sync button

Modify the argument of the constructor of the FileOutputStream to save the file elsewhere

Save them somewhere like 'Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "Android/package.name/files/some_file.xml'

And use the same path to get to the file and use it

I hope this helps

**EDIT:** As per your last comment, you need to identify each device using a uniqur identifier, which is usually hard to find being available on all android devices,I think you'd have to use Sign in/up system and thus means using PHP

Maybe there's better solution though

Comment: thanks for the reply, i'll try to implement this idea. I wanted to ask you what you mean when you say to save the xml files elsewhere? is it not ok if they are saved under "res/values" as default? Also, if the directory where they are stored is changes, how do I refer to them? for the moment, I do it like R.file.resource.

Comment: @helius83 Sorry for the late reply, and no, I CAN'T save files in /res/dynamically, as I said, save it elsewhere, which means you can save it on user's Internal Storage, or whatever path you desire